# Add Calculated Column on Grouped Data

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas and have created 2 pivot tables, and then interleaved them into 1 dataframe using the following code:

```
df_sales = pd.read_sql_query(sales_query, cnxn, params=[report_start, end_mtd, whse])                                
print('executing sales sql for warehouse : ' + whse)                                                                 
df_sales['PERIOD'] = (((df_sales['INV_MONTH'].astype(str) + '/' + df_sales['INV_YEAR'].astype(str))))                
df_sales = pd.pivot_table(df_sales, index=['REP', 'CUST_NO'], columns=['PERIOD'], values=['SALES'], fill_value=0)    

df_profit = pd.read_sql_query(profit_query, cnxn, params=[report_start, end_mtd, whse])                              
print('executing profit sql for warehouse : ' + whse)                                                                
df_profit['PERIOD'] = (((df_profit['INV_MONTH'].astype(str) + '/' + df_profit['INV_YEAR'].astype(str))))             
df_profit = pd.pivot_table(df_profit, index=['REP', 'CUST_NO'], columns=['PERIOD'], values=['PROFIT'], fill_value=0) 

df = pd.concat([df_sales, df_profit], axis=1)[list(interleave([df_sales, df_profit]))]
```

My output looks like this:

```
SALES     PROFIT     SALES    PROFIT       
01/2017    01/2017   02/2017   02/2017
$96.01     $23.18  $7,347.66   $1,267.72    
$600.00    $146.35   $600.00   $147.15
```

I would like to add a calculated `df['MARGIN']` column to this table to give the output of:

```
SALES     PROFIT     MARGIN    SALES       PROFIT      MARGIN
01/2017    01/2017   02/2017   02/2017     02/2017     02/2017
$96.01     $23.18    24.14%    $7,347.66   $1,267.72    17.25%
$600.00    $146.35   24.39%     $600.00    $147.15      24.53%
```

I attempted to use `df['MARGIN'] = df['PROFIT'] / df['SALES']` but got an error:

`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 12, placement implies 1`

Assuming this is the error because I've included 12 periods in my report.

Comment: What is the result of `df['PROFIT']` / `df['SALES']` . Seems like a datatype issue

Comment: @A.Kot they are both float64

Comment: I think the problem is with the duplicate column names.

Comment: Can't you just do `df_profit / df_sales` and interleave as needed? (maybe you need to drop a level of the columns index if they are multiindex, so the column names match)

Comment: @jdehesa I am not sure how to interleave anyway other than how I did.  Do you have a suggestion for a way I can do that?

Comment: Ah, I think I know why what you tried didn't work... I think you can do `df['MARGIN'] = df['PROFIT'] / df['SALES']` if you do it _before_ reordering the columns (just after `pd.concat`)... then reorder as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want as long as your column indices are sorted.

Assuming:

```
df = pd.concat([df_sales, df_profit], axis=1)
```

Gives you a dataframe with two-level hierarchical index for the columns, you can do:

```
df = pd.concat([df_sales, df_profit], axis=1)
df["MARGIN"] = df["PROFIT"] / df["SALES"]
```

If this operation fails is because the column index is not ordered. You can fix it just by doing:

```
df = pd.concat([df_sales, df_profit], axis=1)
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
df["MARGIN"] = df["PROFIT"] / df["SALES"]
```

Then you just interleave the columns as before.

*Update:*

A ugly solution to the final interleaving:

```
n = len(df.columns) // 3
# Using sum for lists is highly discouraged! But convenient in this case :)
cols = sum(([j * n + i for j in range(3)] for i in range(n)), [])
df = df.iloc[:, cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect Pandas to somehow know that when you say that margin is equal to profit divided by sales, what you mean is that margin for a particular date is equal to profit for that date divided by sales for that date? Pandas isn't a mind reader. Assuming you're using multi-indexing, you can do:

```
for reporting_date in df.columns.get_level_values(1):
    df['MARGIN',reporting_date'] = df['PROFIT',reporting_date']/df['SALES',reporting_date']
```

However, that will probably still return an error; given that you have dollars signs and commas, presumably the amounts are stored as strings. You should store them as int or float, and if you really want to see them displayed as dollars, write a display_as_dollars function.

edit: You can also try df['MARGIN'] = df['PROFIT'].div(df['SALES'])